# async.auto results object should have one value but has an array of two

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to use async to interact with MongoDb. My async.auto call for some reason is adding an array of 2 objects to the `results` parameter when there should only be one.

```
    async.auto({
        pantMeasurement: function (callback) {
            app.models.PantMeasurement.findOne({ temp_user_id: req.session.temp_user_id }, function (err, pantMeasurement) {
                var pantData = {'waist', 'length'};
                if (!pantMeasurement) {
                    return app.models.PantMeasurement.create(_.extend({ temp_user_id: req.session.temp_user_id }, pantData), callback);
                }
                _.extend(pantMeasurement, pantData);

                pantMeasurement.save(callback);
            });
        },
        user: ['pantMeasurement', function (callback, results) {
            var name = 'firstName';
            results.pantMeasurement.user_id = name;

            results.pantMeasurement.save(callback);  //ERROR HERE
        }]}, function(err, results) {
            ...
        }
```

In the second task `user` the line `results.pantMeasurement.save(callback);` is throwing an error that `save` does not exist. After stepping through the code, this is because `results` has an array of two `pantMeasurement` objects when there should only be one object and no array. The array consists of the one `pantMeasurement` object and an empty object.

[image]

The code works fine if `!pantMeasurement` is true and a new entry is created in the database. But anytime `pantMeasurement.save(callback)` is called, then I am seeing this error and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention which module you use to access mongodb, but as you use Models, I assume that mongoose is used. If I'm right, please add the mongoose tag to the question. If not, ignore this answer.

The [Mongoose API documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) states that the Model#save() callback has three parameters:

```
function (err, document, numAffected) {
  //...
}
```

- err is the optional error
- document is the document that was saved
- numAffected is 1 if the document was changed in the database and 0 if the document didn't need to be changed (because it was up to date)

In your debugging screenshot you can see, that the second element in the array is not an empty object but the number 0. This number is the numAffected-Parameter that was passed by the save-callback to the async-result, so this is the reason you get an array as result.

To simplify your code, maybe you should consider the [findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) statement which lets you find and update a document in one step. It also accepts an upsert-option that will create a new document if there is none.